# Schur's theorem

Tags: matrices

Let, $A$ be a Hermitian matrix of order $n$. Let, diag$(A)$ denote the vestors whose coordinates are the diagonal entries of $A$ and $\lambda$($A$) denote the vector whose coordinates are the eigen values of $A$ specified in any order. Show that,

diag($A$) majorises $\lambda$(A)

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): It is the eigenvalues that majorize the diagonal elements, cf. [Schur-Horn theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem).

Comment: can you prove it? @ Qmechanic